# Apache ECharts map weird (very basic question)

Tags: echarts

Hi have some trouble getting started with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://echarts.apache.org/examples/vendors/echarts/echarts.min.js?_v_=1574102238076"></script>
    <script src="https://echarts.apache.org/examples/vendors/echarts/map/js/world.js?_v_=1574102238076"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="eChartVersionIt_33_0" style="height: 535px; width: 935px;" ></div>
    <script>
    function distrLocaEu(container, commandName) {
        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById(container));
        option = {
                backgroundColor: '#111',
                geo: {
                    map: 'world',
                },
            }

        myChart.setOption(option);
    };
    distrLocaEu('eChartVersionIt_33_0','ChartDistrLocaEu');
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This should render an empty map of the world.

Indeed, copy/pasting it in JsFiddle works correctly.
If I put in a normal HTML file, both Firefox and Chrome show up a VERY corrupted world

Am I missing something very stupid?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. I was referring the libs using https while in dev mode (http)